# Does "$\varepsilon$ is indistinguishable from zero" mean that $\varepsilon$ is less than any positive real number?

Tags: infinitesimals, synthetic-differential-geometry

I read book "A primer of infinitesimal analysis" John Bell. Author wrote about infinitesimals which indistinguishable from zero.

[image]

Does "$\varepsilon$ indistinguishable from zero" mean that $\varepsilon$ is less than any positive real number?

Thanks.

Comment: I think so. Of course there is no such positive real number. The whole point of infinitesimal analysis is to introduce those numbers in a larger field in a rigorous way that makes calculation correct and theorems provable.

Comment: @EthanBolker, you may want to clarify what exactly is meant by a "field" here, seeing that one is talking about nilsquare infinitesimals :-)  Also, please take a look at this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4788465/72694

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\epsilon$ is a nilsquare infinitesimal, then it will be smaller than any real number $r$ which provably satisfies $r>0$.  Indeed, otherwise $\epsilon$ itself will be provably positive!  The opposite implication may not necessarily hold.  For example, in some models of *Synthetic Differential Geometry*, one has nilpotent infinitesimals that are not provably nilsquare.  For example, one could have provably $\epsilon^3=0$ but $\epsilon^2=0$ is not provable.  Such infinitesimals will also be smaller than every strictly positive real number (for the same reason as mentioned above), but as mentioned are not themselves provably nilsquare.  As I recall there is an appendix at the end of Bell's book that discusses all sorts of classes of infinitesimals.  You could look it up there.

Comment: $\varepsilon$ has no value as $dx$ has. For example, we have $dx=1/N$ but we can't define $\varepsilon$ in this way.

Comment: @Mike_bb, if you define $dx$ as a fraction it will certainly not be a *nilsquare* infinitesimal.  What makes you think that the difference between $\epsilon$ and $dx$ amounts to more than choice of notation?  Does anything in Bell's book lead you to believe that?

Comment: In some sources nilsquare infinitesimal is defined as quantity "so small" that $\varepsilon^2=0$. If it's possible to say so I try to understand what is distinction between definition of $\varepsilon$ in SDG and definition of $dx$ in classical analysis. In both definitions we have small quantities but for some reason $(dx)^2$ isn't zero although $dx$ can be such small as we want. @Mikhail Katz

Comment: @Mike_bb, the phrase " quantity so small that $\epsilon^2=0$" may mean something to a physicist but has little meaning to a mathematician.

Comment: Yes, this phrase confused me. But how to correctly define $\varepsilon$ ? @Mikhail Katz

Comment: @Mike_bb, That's the whole point of Bell's approach (which is based on Lawvere's approach to category theory and intuitionistic logic).  It is not trivial.  The line $R$ of Bell's approach cannot be identified with the usual line $\mathbb R$.